# Meteor - React - Mongo project will not fetch or flash immediatly

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, material-design, yarnpkg

I am just getting started with my project using Meteor/React & MongoDB.

I have pushed my code to below URL:

https://github.com/msc/soccer-app

I have from which insert player name into MongoDB, the insert part seems working fine and return the id and then route to the main page, on that section I do console.log from fetch method, it shows the record has been fetch, but immediately shows another console.log with empty array.

I do not have any error on console or terminal. someone can let me know which part I am doing wrong?

Here is the output of my browser log

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZteX.png)

[Object as soon as insert into MongoDB and then flash][2]

Comment: You should put the part of the code you're having the problem here so that people don't have to keep searching for the code in your folders. Please, be more specific.

Comment: Thanks , But I put the console log which shows line 72 on imports/ui/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go through the tutorial again, if im not mistaken that is a tutorial from Lynda.com right? (I took it myself like 2 weeks ago) Emmanuel Henri's work I found to be very complete.

As for your problem looking at the console it looks like you need to adjust your schema to allow for the createdAt value.

Like isreal.zinc said, you should post the code you are having issues with, people generally are not going to want to dig through an entire codebase.